# Having issues with modifying TextBox from another class

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having an issue where I want to be able to modify a textbox from another class.

I've tried searching and testing solutions, none seemed to do the job. (Invoking for an example..)

Code from class cThread:

```
        class cThread
        {

            public bool closed = false;
            private TcpClient client;
            private StreamReader ins;
            private StreamWriter ots;
            Form1 meow = new Form1();

            public cThread(TcpClient client, StreamReader ins, StreamWriter ots)
            {
                this.client = client;
                this.ins = ins;
                this.ots = ots;
            }

            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    string responseLine;

                    responseLine = meow.bunifuCustomTextbox2.Text;

                    while ((responseLine = ins.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine(responseLine);

                        meow.bunifuCustomTextbox3.Text = responseLine + " test";

                        if (responseLine.IndexOf("*** Adios") != -1)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    closed = true;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
                }
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }
```

This causes an error: `Cross-Thread operation not valid: accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.`

I have also tried this solution:

```
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    string responseLine;

                    meow.bunifuCustomTextbox2.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { responseLine = meow.bunifuCustomTextbox2.Text; }));

                    while ((responseLine = ins.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {

                        Console.WriteLine(responseLine);

                        meow.bunifuCustomTextbox3.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate { meow.bunifuCustomTextbox3.Text = meow.bunifuCustomTextbox2.Text; }));

                        meow.bunifuCustomTextbox3.Text = responseLine + " test";

                        if (responseLine.IndexOf("*** Adios") != -1)
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    closed = true;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
                }
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }
        }
```

This did not work either. Same error.

What I'm expecting to happen is when the user types in a message in bunifuCustomTextbox2, it'll then be set to responseLine which I want to lively be updated by bunifuCustomTextbox3.

Because this is going to be a multiplayer chat and I'm converting this code from a consoleapp to winforms..

sorry if im being a dumb :(

Answer (score 1):

When you access an UI resource from another thread you should have the Dispatcher thread handle that:

```cs
Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { /* UI changes */ });
```

Comment: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Dispatcher.Invoke(Action)'
I get this error, not sure how to fix!

Comment: This is WinForms. `BeginInvoke()` with a delegate (`MethodInvoker()`, usually) is used instead. The problem here is, sadly, the whole structure of the code the OP is presenting. It has to be rewritten from scratch.

Comment: Ah, well, looks like this ain't getting a solve-through. Thanks anyway! I'm not the best programmer..